# vue/cli-plugin-pwa: server requests (with axios) aren’t cached by the service worker

Tags: vue.js, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I’m unsuccessfully trying to add PWA to the project. Server requests aren’t cached by the service worker. Request addresses aren’t added to Cache Storage. Accordingly, the offline mode doesn’t work.

Project config:

- vue spa
- requests to the server using axios library
- server responses don’t contain cache-control header
- pwa is implemented using the standard vue plugin: vue /
  cli-plugin-pwa

PWA config in **vue.config.js:**

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath: '/',
    pwa: {
        name: 'Old Vehicles',
        manifestOptions: {
            name: "Old Vehicles",
            display: "standalone",
            scope: "/",
            start_url: "/"
        },
        workboxPluginMode: 'GenerateSW',
        workboxOptions: {
            navigateFallback: '/index.html',
            runtimeCaching: [{
                urlPattern: new RegExp('^http'),
                handler: 'NetworkFirst',
                options: {
                    networkTimeoutSeconds: 2,
                    cacheName: 'api-cache',
                    cacheableResponse: {
                        statuses: [0, 200],
                    },
                },
            }]
        }
    }
};
```

PS And also this: developer console in browser -> Application tab -> Installability -> "Page does not work offline". The service worker successfully connected (excepting request caching), the manifest is identified. Why does it show such a message?

Comment: `vue.config.js` works as expected and I cannot reproduce the problem. You can serve `dist/` folder on localhost, and check workbox log in devtool `console` tab and network info in `network` tab.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently learning about PWA too. What I read about this issue:

1. **Axios** is using behind the lines **XHR requests** and **not fetch** requests.
2. Because workers run separately from the main thread, service workers are independent of the application they are associated with, **consequences** : [synchronous XHR and localStorage cannot be used in a service worker](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-service-worker#what_is_a_service_worker)

So I guess you may need to use standard fetch requests.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is misleading.

Assuming the service worker is successfully registered/etc, any (https) network request on the main thread (or web worker threads) will be sent via the service worker.

Axios is part of the main thread, not the service worker thread.

XHR in the main thread are the same as any other method (eg js: fetch(), html: , css: url())...all requests will trigger the 'fetch' event in the service worker (presumably to be cached).

The problem is quite likely to be because the network requests in the main thread are http, not https.
If possible, upgrade the server serving the resources from http to https, and change the URLs used on the main thread. It will not be possible to 'rewrite' the protocol in the service worker.

If you cannot change the code on the main thread for some reason (eg legacy app with no source), then it should be possible to get the server that is sending the document that causes the request (ie the js file with fetch('http://.../')/XHR, the html file with <img src="http://.../">, the css file with url(http://.../)) to add a header:

Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests

More info: https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/813

and https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-upgrade-insecure-requests/#goals